# If It is a directory append text

Tags: bash, bash4

Im trying to append a text if it is a directory.

```
calculation="$(ls -l | sed 's/[d]/This is a directory -> /')"

printf "%s" "${calculation}"
```

Im just womdering if somebody could give me a tip on what is wrong with my code

Comment: Replace `[d]` by `^d` to indicate that you expect the `d` at the beginning of a line. Apart from that, are you sure you want to see the whole and even expanded directory listing in one large line?

Comment: What are you after? You should never parse the output of ls.

Comment: @HansKlünder I want to display each file on different line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing, but:

```
$ calculation="$(ls -l | sed 's/^[d]/This is a directory -> d/')"
```

Two changes:

- I added a `^` which says that the line must begin with one of the characters in the square brackets (which `d` is the only one).
- I added a `d` on the end of the substitution, since you *replaced* it with your string. This way, your directories still have the correct permissions.

You don't need `[d]`. Just `d` would do:

```
$ calculation="$(ls -l | sed 's/^d/This is a directory -> d/')"
```

And you don't need `${calculation}`:

```
$ echo "$calculation"
```

or, if you want to use `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$calculation"   # Note the ending NL which printf doesn't supply
```

Or even more simply:

```
$ printf "$calculation\n"
```

Comment: Quite nice! Even simpler: `ls -l | sed 's/^d/This is a directory -> d/'` without the variable `calculation` at all.